# How to force file system to auto mount as read/write?

Tags: mount, filesystem, automount, read-only

Is there a way I can force my flash drive to mount as read/write every single time I plug it in to my computer? At the moment, it's mounting as read-only and I'm trying to use it to store .iso files I've tweaked/customised in my VM but, right now, I can't even download a disk image file to it or create a folder. It is formatted to FAT32 and is 134GB.

[image: Image verifying that the 134GB USB stick formatted to FAT 32]

Comment: That is the normal situation, so you will have to be more specific.

Comment: What file system ?

Comment: @psusi I edited the question; I was trying to keep it as concise as I could so the answer would be a simple "Yes/no. Here's how/why" answer.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I added more information.

Comment: Please check and correct the information you edited. 135GB and FAT32 is NOT possible. Perhaps you meant exFAT, the proprietary file system typically used in any 64GB+ flash drive? If so you need to install support for exFAT before anything else. If, by any chance and with some third party tool, you managed for format it in FAT32, thus violating the FS specs, it won't work, obviously.

Comment: Normally, it's the role of `/etc/fstab` to handle this sort of thing. `man fstab` for details. Quick question: did you buy this 128G USB drive from a reliable source? Many 128G flash drives sold on eBay have much lower capacity, but the drive is manipulated to provide false data: http://www.ebay.com/gds/BEWARE-of-FAKE-128GB-256GB-USB-Flash-Drives-on-eBayeBay-/10000000046978438/g.html

Comment: @barrycarter What I paid was $7 for a 256GB flash drive on Wish. What I got was 134GB. I'm sure it's low quality because I can't partition it.

Comment: @MichaelBay I'm sure it's 134GB and formatted to FAT32. I added a picture from `Disks` to show you. I am formatting it, right now, to ext4. Would that possibly fix it?

Comment: As http://www.instructables.com/id/Dont-fall-for-the-Flash-Drive-Scam!/ notes, it's highly unlikely a $7 drive has even 134GB on it.

Comment: Nice find, @barrycarter . I knew about this fakes but could never imagine we would find one here but now it's kinda obvious what the problem is. Amolith, this is a waste of time (and a waste of $7), a cheap128GB flash drive costs ~$50 at Amazon. There are no "134GB" drives and FAT32 supports up to 32GB partitions only. Yours is a fake.

Comment: @MichaelBay, excuse me?  According to wikipedia, fat32 supports 2 TiB.

Comment: @psusi True. Theoretically it's 2TB but using the native Windows Disk Management the largest partition size it allows is 32GB, the *de facto* limitation in practical, "real world", terms. That's the main reason for the industry wide adoption of exFAT as the file system for any flash drive larger than 32GB (the other reason reason being the FAT32's file size limitation of ~4GB).

Comment: @MichaelBay, leave it to Microshaft to prevent you from doing something that used to work just fine to force you to use their proprietary new fs.  Format it in Ubuntu and I'll bet Windows will happily use it even if it won't let you format it.

Comment: @psusi No doubt it would work *if* we were talking about a good drive and not a fake. Can you find a real "134GB" drive? If you can I pay you dinner at Jamie Oliver's Fifteen.

Comment: Could you please (1) verify the file system integrity (with `fsck` or Windows’ tools), (2) run `sudo dmesg | tail -n 50` shortly after the file system on the drive in question was mounted and [edit] your question to include its output as well as (3) that of `tail -n 1 /proc/mounts`? Thanks.